# How do I stop vue eslint rules from changing?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli, eslint-plugin-vue

I had a team member run npm install earlier today, and now eslint want the tags to use camel case instead of dashes. That means that every single place we have a `<v-btn>` or a `<v-tab>` is getting changed to `<VBtn>` or `<VTab>`. This seems to be because of an update to eslint-plugin-vue, which changed the default for the `vue/camelcase` rule.

I fixed this in the eslint rules, but I'm not sure what other settings might change. Obviously we don't want the whole repository to switch styles whenever someone updates a package. How can we freeze the other lint settings?

Comment: Can you post your eslint config?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your eslintrc file and set it to your preferred value

Comment: I mean in general. Adding this rule stopped eslint from changing this rule. I want to prevent eslint from changing any rules in the future.

Comment: Fix the version of every eslint dependency in package.json, then it will never update